# Problem with making an estimate when values of many variables are unknown?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, inequalities

Hi all, I was wondering whether you could help me understand a part in a proof that is assumed to be an "obvious detail" by the author, but that I can't wrap my head around. Essentially, as far as I can understand, there are two values $A$ and $B$, and we want to prove that:

$\Bigg|A-B \; \Bigg| > \frac{1}{p}$

for some polynomial $p$  (the actual value of $p$ is unimportant).

We reach a point in the proof where we have shown that

$\Bigg |\alpha \cdot A- \beta \cdot B \; \Bigg| \geq \frac{2}{p}$

and that

$\Bigg|\; \alpha - \beta\; \Bigg| < \frac{1}{3p^2} $

The next line of the proof (where I stop understanding) concludes that

$\Bigg |\beta \cdot A- \beta \cdot B \; \Bigg| > \frac{1}{p}$

from which point we can make several conclusions.

Can anyone explain how to arrive at the last inequality from the previous ones? Is it possible, or am I missing some additional information somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: I think there must be an upper bound for *A* somewhere. The step troubling you should be the triangle inequality applied, but to conclude that the term you discard is at most 1/*p* you do need something.

Comment: You need some property of A.  Knowing that A is an integer would help.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.25

Comment: I'm sorry, probably an important detail is that A and B are probabilities, so they are bounded above by 1. I'm having trouble understanding how we could replace $\alpha$ in the 3rd to last inequality by $\beta$ (giving us the last inequality) 

Comment: Actually, Charles's suggestion is better than mine.  Having A integral would work for a different system of inequalities, similar but not identical to what is given.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.25

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are also probabilities, but I'm not sure that is too important

Comment: If you call the first quantity C and note it is bounded away from 0 by 2/p, and call the second quantity D, how close are C and D?  With A at most 1the and the step size less than 1/p, I can see how D is still far from 0.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.25

Comment: In the above, I assume p < 3p^2, which would hold for all sensible values of p, namely positive integers.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.25

Comment: $|\beta A-\beta B| \ge |\alpha A-\beta B| - |(\alpha-\beta)A|$ so you have to show $|(\alpha-\beta)A|<1/p$ and then you're done. Using your inequality for $|\alpha-\beta|$, it suffices to show that $A<3p$. Of course this is fine if $p>1/3$ since $A$ is a probability.

Comment: Ok, I know that $p$ is greater than $\frac{1}{3}$, so I'm all set. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we truly have (as you say in the comments) that $0 \leq \alpha,\beta, A, B \leq 1$ then 
$$
\frac2p \leq |\alpha A - \beta B| \leq 1
$$
implying that $p \geq 2$.

This in turn means that $\frac{A}{3p^2} \leq \frac1{3p^2} \leq \frac1{6p}$.

Letting
$$
\epsilon=\beta-\alpha
$$
and using
$$
\left| \beta \cdot A - \beta \cdot B \right| = \left| \alpha \cdot A + \epsilon \cdot A- \beta \cdot B \right|
$$
plus the triangle inequality shows that your condition is easily satisfied.